# Redirect to login page

Tags: redirect, login, wp-redirect

I am new to wordpress. I am running wordpress setup on `http://localhost/wordpress/`. I am facing two problems right now:

- Only the logged in users can access the site. So, I am trying to redirect the guest from home page to login page using the following code which is somehow isn't working:

> Path: `wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/header.php`

```
        <?php
            if(get_permalink() != wp_login_url() && !is_user_logged_in()){
                wp_redirect( wp_login_url() ); exit;
            }
        ?>
```

Since the above code wasn't working, I tried to move on by letting the user to login manually by clicking on the `login` button. Here is the working code:

```
<?php
    if(get_permalink() != wp_login_url() && !is_user_logged_in()){
        // wp_redirect( wp_login_url() ); exit;
?>
        <a href="<?php echo wp_login_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" title="Login">Login</a>
<?php
    }
?>
```

- From above code, when guest clicked on login  he/she was redirecting to login page and When the user is logs in, the page is redirecting to wordpress admin i.e `wp-admin` instead of home page i.e `http://localhost/wordpress`.

#### What I am trying to do is:

- Redirect the guest from home page to login page, if the user isn't logged in.
- And then redirect the user from login page to home page instead of wp-admin, when user logs in.

Comment: When you talk about "home page" do you really refer to "home" (i.e. https://example.com) or to any other page in the "front end"?

Comment: @cybmeta I meant `http://localhost/wordpress`.

Comment: @cybmeta guest users can't access any page of the site. When guests visit `http://localhost/wordpress`, they must be redirected to login page. and when the log in, they must be redirected to `http::localhost/wordpress`. Apart from the above description, if the guest is on other page than the home page for example `http://localhost/wordpress/about` then the guest will still be redirected to login page and when he/she logs in, they will be redirected to `http://localhost/wordpress/about`.

Comment: Ok. Now it is clear. So, the user should be redirected to the page he/she was trying to see as guest.

Comment: @cybmeta yes I meant the same :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you need to check if the user is logged in, if not, redirect it to login page. If the user logs in succesfully, he should be redirected to the page he was trying to see. You can do this by using the `redirect` argument of [`wp_login_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_url).

This code should work (not tested):

```
add_action( 'init', 'cyb_restrict_guest_access' );
function cyb_restrict_guest_access() {
    global $wp;
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() && ! cyb_is_login_page() ) {
        wp_redirect( wp_login_url( site_url( $wp->request ) ) );
        exit;
    }
}

function cyb_is_login_page() {
    return in_array($GLOBALS['pagenow'], array('wp-login.php'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code to check home page or not:

```
        if(is_home() && !is_user_logged_in()){
            wp_redirect( wp_login_url() ); exit;
        }
```

Comment: I am trying the same as you can see in my above code. Somehow it isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

This in your header.php or before the get_header() call in any template will redirect a user who isn't logged in and who tries to reach any page of your site to the login page:

```
if( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_redirect( wp_login_url() );
    exit;
}
```

This will redirect all users to the home page after login:

```
function tbdn_login_redirect( $redirect_url ) {

    return home_url();

}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'tbdn_login_redirect' );
```

Note that it doesn't restrict a logged in user from accessing admin screens if they know the URL or if their login has the admin bar enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If your 'Login' page is a 'Page Template', you can use '`template_redirect`' hook. The following code in your `functions.php` will get you these:

- Redirect the guest from home page to login page, if the user isn't
  logged in.
- And redirect the user from login page to home page when user logs in.

Add the following in your functions file:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'ft_redirect_user' );
function ft_redirect_user() {
  //Redirect the guest from home page to login page, if the user isn't logged in. And redirect the user from login page to home page when user logs in.
  if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && is_front_page() ) {
    $return_url = esc_url( home_url( '/login-page-slug/' ) ); //change the 'login-page-slug' to your actual page slug of your login page.
    wp_redirect( $return_url );
    exit;
  } elseif ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page( 'login-page-slug' ) ) { //change the 'login-page-slug' to your actual page slug of your login page.
    $return_url = esc_url( home_url('/') );
    wp_redirect( $return_url );
    exit;
  }
}
```